# No ImageIcon display

Tags: java, image, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I use Java to build a simple interface, and it says no error. However it can't display the 1ImageIcon1 on the button (it only has the name of the button.). How can I fix it?

Here is the code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Hi everyone");
    frame.setSize(500,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel pane=new JPanel();

    Font font=new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.BOLD,20);
    JLabel label=new JLabel("How about a presidation quote");
    label.setFont(font);
    pane.add(label);


    ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon("ChenGao.jpg");
    JButton ChenGao = new JButton("ChenGao",icon);
    ChenGao.setHorizontalTextPosition(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    ChenGao.setVerticalTextPosition(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
    pane.add(ChenGao);

    JTextArea textArea= new JTextArea(10,40);
    textArea.setText("Yes we can");
    pane.add(textArea);

    frame.setContentPane(pane);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: When you pass `ImageIcon` a `String`, it expects that a file on the file system, relative to where your program was executed exists.  1- Where is the image actually stored and 2- Try using `ImageIO.read` to load the file

Comment: Hi, I store the image in the src file.

Comment: You can try ImageIcon icon=new ImageIcon("src/ChenGao.jpg"); but you'd better create a resource folder to store image

Comment: Hi, I tried it. but it's a litter strange. When I add a another new button, if I didn't give the new button an image icon, it will automatically use the previous image.

Comment: It only happens when I put the image in src folder. Now i use a new image folder under project path. It works well

Answer (score 1):

Generally, there are (at least) two types of "resources" that get discussed, external and internal.

An external resource is one that resides outside of the application context, such as a file on the file system.  An internal resource is one the resides within the context of the application.  These are also know as embedded resources, as they live within the classpath context of the application, normally within one or more Jar files.

In this case, you can not access them like normal files, instead, you need to use `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsInputStream`, depending on your needs.

Based on your comments, I would suggert that you need to use either

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("ChenGao.jpg"));
```

or maybe

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ChenGao.jpg"));
```

Depending on where the image is relative to the class trying to load it.

You may also need to supply a path if the image is contained within some directory within the source directory

Because `ImageIcon` doesn't provide any useful information if loading failed for some reason, you're normally better off using `ImageIO` to load your images.  This will, at least, throw an  exception if something goes wrong

Check out [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can read Oracle's online API about [ImageIcon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html#ImageIcon%28java.lang.String%29).
use a relative path like:

```
 new ImageIcon("src/ChenGao.jpg")
```

Comment: You should never reference anything within `src` path as it will not be available when deployed...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use a new image folder under the project path. it works well